# Migrating some objects from one database to another

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, dump

How can I dump one user with all his associations (comments, posts etc) from one database (development, sqlite) to insert it another (production, mysql).

Should I dump it into yaml or to sql or something else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok.

`God Save the YAML`

I've used YAML dumping into file from development and loading this in my production. There was hack with id, that have changed, due it is auto_increament.

*development*

```
user     = User.find X
posts    = user.posts
comments = user.comments
...
File.open("user.yml", "w")    { |f| f << YAML::dump(user) }
File.open("comments.yml", "w"){ |f| f << YAML::dump(comments) }
File.open("posts.yml", "w")   { |f| f << YAML::dump(posts) }
...
```

*production*

```
user     = YAML::load_file("user.yml")
posts    = YAML::load_file("posts.yml")
comments = YAML::load_file("comments.yml")
new_user = user.clone.save # we should clone our object, because it isn't exist
posts.each do |p|
  post = p.clone
  post.user = new_user
  post.save
end
...
```

Comment: Note for Rails 3.1+ use `user.dup.save`

Comment: Adding to George Chen's comment: for Rails 3.1+ use `post = p.dup`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this gem: https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db

> YamlDb is a database-independent
>   format for dumping and restoring data.
>   It complements the the
>   database-independent schema format
>   found in db/schema.rb. The data is
>   saved into db/data.yml.

Comment: I know this gem. It is pretty nice and I use it often to dump and load in my development. But it is not I need. It dumps entire database but I need to transfer only exact data I need.

Comment: Actually, I don't know about associations, but this guy added a table dump https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db/pull/14. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: No, I still need to dump exact objects (lines in database). Anyway thanks :) I am dumping my objects into YAML now. It works but looks brute for me, so I've asked this question

Comment: I've added solution I've used