# Is there a way to export partial data from MySQL to SQlite using rails/ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I know that yaml_db gem can export the whole MySQL database into SQlite, but I have too many things and I only need some tables.

Is there an easy way to define which tables and which records to export from MySQL to SQlite?

Just to clarify a bit more, I still want to have both databases, but I need to export some of the MySQL data into SQlite.

Edit:
http://www.coshx.com/blog/2013/01/15/migrating-specific-data-from-mysql-to-sqlite

I tried this, but didn't work quite well.. It takes too long and sometimes it doesn't import the whole set of data

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating some objects from one database to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700520/migrating-some-objects-from-one-database-to-another)